# Flask websockets: Emitting to specific sockets

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I am trying to track a number of websocket connections and send specific information to each one. Here is my method using Flask websocket-io, which I've lifted from a reply on [this](https://gist.github.com/ericremoreynolds/dbea9361a97179379f3b) site.

```
class Socket:
    def __init__(self, sid):
        self.sid = sid
        self.connected = True

    def emit(self, event, data):
        socketio.emit(event, data, room=self.sid)

sockets = {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def foo():
    sid = str(request.sid)
    sockets[sid] = Socket(sid)
    sockets[sid].emit('connected', {'myID':sid})
    info = getInfo(sid)
    sockets[sid].emit('info', {'data':info})
```

This all works wonderfully as expected. The problem comes then when I try to iterate through and update everyone:

```
def refreshInfo():
    for sid in sockets:
        info = getInfo(sid)
        sockets[sid].emit('info', {'data':info})
```

The Socket method receives the same sid and the same info as when it's first called. But the client does not receive anything. What gives? Thanks in advance.